# How do I go from an EF Core navigation property to a nested Web API JSON response?

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to follow some basic .Net core tutorials, I want to create an Asp.net Core Web API that uses EF Core.

Basically .Include() appears to do nothing, and I did not even think that was going to be a necessary call at first to be honest.

I have an API that has Goldfish who have Ideas, JSON is being returned nicely for the separate objects, except that my navigation property is always NULL on goldfish:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "isAlive": true,
    "food": 50,
    "ideas": null
},..
```

Here is the Goldfish class (it does not work for ICollection either)

```
 public class Goldfish
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }
    public long Food { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Idea class (I am using a foreignkey attribute out of desperation to make it work, previously I had a GoldfishID property.

```
    public class Idea
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Gist { get; set; }
    public long GoldfishID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GoldfishID")]
    public Goldfish Goldfish { get; set; }

}
```

I think my database is OK, as the foreign key has been setup on my Idea table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ideas]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Ideas_Goldfish_GoldfishID] FOREIGN KEY([GoldfishID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Goldfish] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

But when I access my controller method:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Goldfish> GetAll()
    {
        var stuff = _context.Goldfish.Include(i => i.Ideas);

        return stuff.ToList();
       // return _context.Goldfish.ToList();
    }
```

Thanks to my favourite tool in the whole world, I know the SQL that runs has no join, or any attempt to get ideas - my goldfish are brain dead :(

```
    SELECT [g].[ID], [g].[Food], [g].[IsAlive], [g].[Name]
FROM [Goldfish] AS [g]
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong...is my return type excluding the type of structure I want? I will say that I have not set up the desired one-to-many explicitly in OnModelCreating since the tutorial did not do so, here is my whole context:

```
    public class GoldfishContext : DbContext
{
    public GoldfishContext(DbContextOptions<GoldfishContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Goldfish> Goldfish { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }

    //Interrupt the standard configuration of table names, the tutorial has this and it's nice to keep ffr
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Goldfish>().ToTable("Goldfish");


    }
}
```

I should mention! I added these ideas in my DBInitialise and they definitely exist in the db:

```
            var pondideas = new Idea[]
        {
            new Idea {Title="Bobs idea", Gist = "Give bob food", GoldfishID=1},
            new Idea {Title="Bobs second idea", Gist = "Give bob more food", GoldfishID=1},
            new Idea {Title="Nice idea", Gist = "Feed everyone", GoldfishID=1},
            new Idea {Title="terrible idea", Gist = "Feed nobody", GoldfishID=1}
        };
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of EF core ?

Comment: Ah! it looks like I added the .Net framework package to get the Include() method and that was the problem, however it now gives me what I wanted but only sends partial responses! i.e. Postman says no response and Chrome shows the beginnings of my desired structure.
The fix was to add  .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
which I find rather obscure for something so common! thank you! I hope this question helps a future me.

Comment: There is nothing "obscure". The one library is called JSON.NET and the other is EntityFramework Core. One doesn't know anything about the other. Also enabling references is a good thing as otherwises it would silently stop on first reference if it already exists further up and the user may wonder why its incomplete. An exception is explicit and tells the user about the problem and when he disables it he's well aware of that behavior

Comment: Also you shouldn't ever return EF Core models from the API, because of this. Always transforms the models into a structure suitable for your WebAPI responses (i.e. by removing reverse navigation properties)

Answer (score 0):

Having been pointed in the right direction (thanks Shyju), I want to put the solution in clear terms:

The correct package for .Include() is 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

For which you need to add:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

The code **will** run with the wrong version (.Net framework) but include will do nothing.

Once you have the right library added, and if your models are linked like mine, your API will timeout unless you add the following JsonOptions into your Startup to prevent circular reference chaos:

```
            services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```